# Bigger performance hit - Empty functions or if statements checking one global variable?

Tags: javascript

Client-side javascript - I am wondering which of these takes up more memory (impacts performance more) in a client browser:

```
1) calling ~60 empty functions (console.log being called as a rewritten empty function)

or 2) calling ~60 if (var == something)'s which are all false.
```

If that's too vague or there's no universally applicable answer, that's fair, just wondering if someone has insight.

Thanks much!

Comment: Since JavaScript treats everything as an array, setting dummy or empty functions and calling each should be faster than checking to see if they exist.